# Razor Pages - reusable components?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to have components for reusable items?

Example 1: a menu is always displayed on every page,

- If account active is "business" display business menu items.
- If account active is "personal" display personal menu items.

Example 2: Notifications are displayed on every page and a new notification will trigger a red badge counter next to the notification icon.

Comment: Sure. Using Partial Views (and rendering them with `@Html.Action()`) or by using `HtmlHelper` extension methods to generate your components (for your 2nd case, I assume you mean like SO inbox or achievements - in which case you will want to use SignalR or a similar framework)

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you mean @Html.Partial(...)?

Comment: No I mean `@Html.Action()` (which calls a sever method that returns a partial)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a reusable items and this is the benefit of the partial view
which can be impeded at the main view.
however if you are asking about displaying menu in each page based on the role of the user you should do the following:

1. Create partial view for the business menu and another one for the personal menu.
2. Render both the partial views at the main layout of your application.
3. Add condition at the razor view "layout" based on the role of the user for displaying the menu (i.e., if the role of the user Admin display the business menu else display the personal menu).